# Decoupling Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Most apps I've written that use Core Data follow the common pattern - the model classes inherit from `NSManagedObject` and are created by insertion into an `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Since I'm evaluating a couple of different persistence options on a new side project, I'd love to find a way to separate out the Core Data implementation from the rest of the code. For example, I might instead use the concept of a `DataStore`, defined using a protocol. It requires that any implementations provide certain functionality. For example `getCars`, `addCar`, and `deleteCar`. The app shouldn't need to know whether `getCars` is fetching from Core Data, Realm, a local file, etc.

One of the immediate problems I've run into with a Core Data implementation of `DataStore` is that as soon as `Car` is added as an entity to the data model, I can't create a `Car` object except via the designated initializer, which expects a context to insert into. This obviously won't fly, since the whole point is to separate any knowledge of the `NSManagedObjectContext` etc from the various view controllers and other classes.

I was thinking about using some other name for all my the Core Data entities (e.g. `CDCar`) and then adding a bunch of code for mapping to/from `CDCar` and `Car`. Or perhaps making a protocol for `Car` for general use in the app, to which `CDCar` will conform. Is there a more common approach to this?

Comment: Please remember that by using extra layer, like your `Car` object you'll loose most powerful CoreData mechanism which is `faulting` specially relation-ships faulting. When fetching `Car` you will also need to fetch `Engine` entity, `Owner` entity etc. You will have to build graph for all related objects.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I didn't consider that. Might be a deal breaker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a parallel entity adds a lot of complexity, to the point where it's not clear that the decoupling would be a net benefit.

What I'd do is include factory methods on the `DataStore` class to create instances on demand. Instead of non-`DataStore` code creating a `Car` directly, it'd call a new `createCar` method on `DataStore`. `DataStore` does whatever it needs to do to create a valid instance and returns the result. That would probably mean you don't need `addCar` since you wouldn't be creating instances outside of `DataStore`.